# PDF to DjVu converter that keeps the OCR layer

Tags: pdf, document-converter, ocr, djvu

I need a quality PDF to DjVu converter that keeps the OCR layer, and that runs on Windows/linux.

Comment: Which of the solutions at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Help:DjVu_files have you explored?

Comment: @Nemo None keeps the text/OCR layer, why are you asking?

Comment: No special reason, just «Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!» http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask